# For how long Linux system logs are stored?

Tags: logs

So that is my question. I googled it but nothing came.
 I see that the logs I have only covers 24 hours (if the time is not wrong, because it resets on every boot)

Comment: In Ubuntu it's usually 30 days, not sure about "Linux systems" in general. Other distros may have different preferences.

Answer (score 4):

Logs are controlled by `logrotate`. It keeps a configurable number of `*.log.1`, `*.log.2.gz`, ... files (compressing old ones).

See `man logrotate`, `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate` and `/etc/logrotate.conf`.

Reading logs can most easily be done with `journalctl` - see `man journalctl`, and [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-journalctl-to-view-and-manipulate-systemd-logs)